# Comparing pointers for self-assignment

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to overload the = operator on a simple C++ class called Set that contains a dynamic array of ints. For the = operator, I first want to check for self assignment, so I wanted to compare 2 pointers to make see if they have the same memory address. Here's the code:

```
Set& Set::operator=(const Set& setEqual)
{
//first check for self assignment
if(setEqual == this*)
    cout << "this is self assignment";
}
```

The error spat out is `error: expected primary-expression before ')' token`

I believe I'm having a misunderstanding of pointers again, so if anyone could point (ha!) me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you use [the copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) you don't need the self assignment test (and you get lots of other benefits).

Comment: 4th line:  To dereference a pointer you put * before the variable name, so it's `*variableName`, not `variableName*`

Comment: "This*" just reminds of "This is star plus, and you are watching star movies." No offense only fun.

Comment: Use the copy-and-swap idiom, you're off track trying to do it this way.

Comment: I will definitely look into the copy and swap idiom, didn't know that took care of everything. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect self-assignment you  need

```
if(&setEqual == this)
```

you should never use

```
if(setEqual == *this)
```

for detecting self-assignment as the latter statement will invoke comparison of the objects, which might be overloaded in the way you don't expect and is likely slower as well.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I am overloading the ++ operator in this class too, so I will definitely do it the first way.

Answer (score 6):

The error is becuase `this*` is not valid - `*` is either infix (in multiplication) or prefix (in dereferencing pointers).

You probably want **`&setEqual == this`** - that is assigning from an object at the same memory address or `setEqual==*this` - comparing equality using whatever `operator==` you have defined

Comment: No, it would be silly to compare the sets. To avoid self-assignment he wants to compare pointers to the set objects, i.e. `this == &setEqual`. But as remarked for the question, he'd be better off using the copy-and-swap idiom (in particular for exception safety).

Comment: I didn't even read what he was comparing, i just saw the syntax error and then gave the two possible (syntactically) correct ways of comparing equality. regardless, i feel its better to be complete - maybe he does want them compared as equal if both sets contain the name ethel, he didn't say!

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked out. I'm still iffy on pointer symantics. That's a good explanation on where I should put the * and why.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare the address of the thing pointed too you really want this:

```
Set& Set::operator=(const Set& setEqual)
{
//first check for self assignment
if(&setEqual == this)
    cout << "this is self assignment";
}
```

Using `(setEqual==*this)` as sugested by some of the solutions compares if the objects are equal under `operator==`.