# C++: is "this" pointer useless?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, this

in the code below, it does not matter whether i put "this->" or remove it. it gives same output and result in both cases.
So, what is the point of having the "this" pointer in C++? Are there other usages where it is essential?
Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class square{
    int l;
    int w;
    public:
        square(int x, int y){
            w = x;
            l = y;
        }
        int getArea(){
            return w * l;
        };
        bool AreaSmallerThan(square c){
            if(this->getArea() < c.getArea())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

};

int main(){
    square A(2,3);
    square B(1,3);
    if(A.AreaSmallerThan(B))
        cout<<"A is smaller than B."<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"A is NOT smaller than B."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the `if -else` statement is even more useless than the `this->` in that function. It should be `bool AreaSmallerThan(square c) { return getArea() < c.getArea(); }` You may also want to change that parameter to `square const& c` to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: It has it's uses. If you choose good naming practices, you generally won't need to use it often.

There are a number of cases where you would want a "pointer to the current object", for example:

```
struct Foo
{
    void MakeCallback(eventid_t eventId)
    {
        scheduleCallback(eventId, callbackProxyFn, this);
    }

    static void callbackProxyFn(eventid_t eventId, Foo* foo)
    {
        // call 'callback' on the relevant object instance.
        foo->callback(eventId);
    }

    void callback(eventid_t eventId);
};
```

It can also be used to resolve conflicts between names in the current object and other scopes, if you choose to use terrible naming conventions.

```
void Foo::bar(int n)
{
    this->n = n;
}
```

You could avoid this (pun intended) scenario, as is common practice, by prefixing statics, globals and members:

```
class Player {
    int m_score;
public:
    Player(int score) : m_score(score) {}
};

Player g_player1;
static Player s_login; // yeah, I know, terrible, just an example tho.
```

A common use is in eliminating self in copy/comparison operators:

```
bool Foo::operator==(const Foo& rhs) const
{
    if (this == &rhs)
         return true;
    ...
}
```

You can also use it to produce a reference to the current object:

```
foo(const Foo&);

void foo(*this);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes there are times it is essential.  A classic case is in `operator=`, to avoid destroying resources during self-assignment.

for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975092/103167

```
Set& Set::operator=(const Set& setEqual)
{
  //first check for self assignment
  if (&setEqual == this)
    cout << "this is self assignment";
  return *this;
}
```

(Note that this isn't needed when using the copy-and-swap idiom)

Accessing members via `this` is also frequently seen in template code which inherits from a template parameter.  Those inherited names can only be found during second phase lookup, which means they need to be qualified with `this->`

Comment: "...which means they need to be qualified with this->" I encountered this one once, and I thought it was a bug in the compiler. Does this rule has a name I can look up?

Comment: @C.R.: Dependent names in two-phase lookup.   See 14.6.2.1p5 in n3936

Answer (score 6):

Random example...what if you had passed an `int w, int l` into your `getArea()` function...then you need to use the `this` keyword to differentiate between the local parameter

```
int getArea(int w, int l){
        return this->w * this->l;
    };
```

Another common example might be **move assignment**. I have pasted an example from a Tree datastructure project I coded.

```
     /* move assignment */
    TreeSet& operator= (TreeSet&& rhs)
    {
        clearAll(rootPtr);
        this->rootPtr = rhs.rootPtr;
        rhs.rootPtr = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
```

And finally another example for an iterator I wrote...when overloading the ++ operator on an iterator, you want to return the resulting iterator..

```
 /* Update the current pointer to advance to the node
         * with the next larger value
         */
        const_iterator& operator++ () {
            //I have deleted all the logic for the sake of not taking up a ton of space..
            return *this;
        }
```

Comment: That's hardly essential.  Most of us consider it terrible style to intentionally create name conflicts.

Comment: perhaps, as I said, "Random example" ..first thing that jumped into my head... it is however a legitimate use for the keyword...

Comment: It's also not needed.  `ClassName::w` and `ClassName::l` also work.

Comment: `return *this` is a great example though.  +1

Comment: I have included another example outside of my first example

Comment: @BenVoigt I've met a number of other people who swear by constructors that use named parameters identical to their variable declarations. Believe it specifically indicates what parameters are being passed for what purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed a minute to think :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the 'this' pointer can be useful when an instance of a class is invoking some method and the instance itself needs to be passed from within the method to some function outside of the class.